# Twitter Bootstrap não carrega nos arquivos jsp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou com um problema, minhas páginas jsp não carregam os CSS do bootstrap.
Gostaria de saber se há alguma configuração em algum xml ou em outro lugar que precisa ser feita, ou apenas colocar as pastas do bootstrap dentro do webapp resources e pronto?

Obrigado.

Comment: só colocar o bootstrap dentro do webapp e inserir a tag `<link />` apontando para ele.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando apenas jsp não precisa nenhuma configuração, a principio a pasta webapp é a pasta acessível pela web, então só precisa colocar o arquivo la e colocar a tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="caminho/do/arquivo"/>`.